# Which constitutions adopt the Universal Declaration of Human Rights?

Tags: constitutional-law, human-rights

I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Declaration_of_Human_Rights#Significance):

> Even though it is not legally binding, the Declaration has been adopted in or has influenced most national constitutions since 1948.

So, which constitutions adopt the Universal Declaration of Human rights?

Comment: By "adopt" do you mean contains a provision that specifically refers to the UDHR, or do you mean "copies/paraphrases many provisions of UDHR"?

Comment: Hi! I didn't think about that. I think mainly the first. I would also like to know which constitutions have been influenced, but I wanted to keep the question focused.